# Is it possible to use checkboxes to determine what data is in a list?

Tags: google-sheets

This is hobby related, so feel free to ignore.
I want to learn how to use Google sheets, and am doing so by building a partial DnD character sheet, piece by piece.

*I am trying not to use scripts as I don't have knowledge to understand how it's working*

**Problem Background**

I have 10 checkboxes, where each box corresponds with a list. If a box is checked, that corresponding list will appear in an answer column, and multiple checks will add multiple lists as one list in the answer column

**Problem**

How do I populate this answer list using the checkboxes?

**My method**

When I check a box as true, it returns a named range as a string. I use the indirect function and the index function to make this into a list, but I feel that this is not a good way to do it.

I'm not sure how to paste cells to demonstrate what I mean, so I can only use images sorry.

*Also, I now realise Class is mislabeled as Race.*

[image: The list in red is populated due to the first checkbox. I am not successful in adding the other lists]

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet and also provide an example of the expected outcome

Comment: My expected outcome, columns are hidden. It's really slow though, I think because I have some functions verifying entire columns. But I've achieved one solution

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15lVz6ZxAuJQ-dnREwdtPkPxofpCUuD7g67U2RTtkPvE/edit#gid=1879940957

Comment: sheet is permission protected

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution I have is to create an IF function for each checkbox

If the box is checked, a Join function is used to turn the list (or array) assigned to that check box into a string, with a "-" delimiter to separate

A new array contains the checkbox states information, either it is full of strings corresponding with any checked box, or if unchecked, it returns a FALSE in that cell

A filter function filters the new array of all FALSE results so only the strings remain

A join function connects these strings into one string

Then tranpose(split()) functions will create a combined array from this string and the end result is as I desired.

Again, sorry I don't know how to post examples. I tried to explain as clearly as I could

I'm sure there is probably a more efficient way to do it, and would appreciate any feedback

Comment: is this an answer to your question or addendum to your question?

Comment: I visited the sheet. There were no checkboxes set up anywhere. And the sheet is "View Only." If you'd like to set permissions to "Anyone with the link can Edit," and if you set up a sheet to match what you have in your original post, it would be easier for people here to help you find solutions. (Protocol is that we'd set up a duplicate sheet to work on.)